# Building dynamically driven web sites with Mason (Perl) with httpd on OpenBSD current

Tags: perl, openbsd, fastcgi, openbsd-httpd

Is it possible to build dynamically driven web sites with Mason (Perl) with httpd on OpenBSD current?

See [*The Mason Book*](http://masonbook.houseabsolute.com/) and [the introduction to OpenBSD's httpd](https://www.openbsd.org/papers/httpd-slides-asiabsdcon2015.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

From the PDF you linked to, I see that

`Only the most important features will be supported: 
–
Serve static files 
–
Support 
FastCGI
–
Do (proper) TLS 
–
Provide “core” features like directory listing, logging, basic auth.`

which means that you will probably need another webserver which can serve dynamic content.